# .net core switch expression incrementing with wrong value

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, local-functions

I was playing around with my intcode computer implementation (from advent of code 2019) and found that when I implemented the switch (to select which operation to execute) it was taking the wrong value.

The following code demonstrates this.
`InstructionPointer` had a value of `2`, `opcode` had the value of `6` which means that `OpcodeJumpIfFalse` will be used. Function `Jif()` is called just fine, and it returns a value, in my case it was returning `0`. `Jif()` also modified the value of `InstructionPointer`, changing its value to `9`. The `InstructionPointer` would the be increased by `0` (return value of `Jif()`) and I would expect its value to be `9`, but its value would go back to being `2`.

```cs
         InstructionPointer += opcode switch
         {
            OpcodeAdd => Add(),
            OpcodeMultiply => Mul(),
            OpcodeInput => Inp(),
            OpcodeOutput => Out(),
            OpcodeJumpIfTrue => Jit(),
            OpcodeJumpIfFalse => Jif(),
            OpcodeLessThan => Let(),
            OpcodeEquals => Equ(),
            OpcodeAdjustRelativeBase => Arb(),
            OpcodeHalt => End(),
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
         };
```

Minimal example which shows same behavior:

```cs
         int j = 2;
         int i = 1;

         int A()
         {
            j = 10;
            return 0;
         }

         j += i switch
         {
            1 => A(),
            _ => throw new Exception()
         };

         Console.WriteLine(j);
```

I did notice that Resharper (in the minimal example) is telling me the assignment is unused in `A()`.

My question is, why does this happen? Is the value of `j` "captured" before the switch? Is this expected behavior?

For now, I have changed my code to use a temporary variable, which resolves the issue, but I would still like to know what is going on here.

Comment: There is a copy of `j` variable, as you can see in [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQJYB2ALogFaIC8iYA3LAJACGzWh0QReMfoKaIAghSl8sMAQLacIABgmq+IAOyJtigL6xFbANScRAZwDutRgGMAFouW6IHAHxyKADSKfAD6voiMrgBOAPb2iPQApvEAogAezokADoy0MfQKKgImEoogEACcpCzkEjRmMCZAA===)

Comment: This is about lambdas and closure, not switch expressions or .NET Core. Whether you use a lambda or local function, you get a *copy* of `j` inside the function. This is no quirk or accident - that's how you ensure the lambda uses the *original* value inside eg a loop or async method

Comment: It's not even to do with lambdas or closures -- you get exactly the same effect without them. It's just that `a += b` is the same as `a = a + b`, so it evaluates `a` before evaluating `b`, and then does the assignment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that the compound assignment operator `a += b` is the same as `a = a + b` (except that `a` is evaluated only once), see §7.17.2 of the spec.

Here's a slightly simpler example which doesn't use a switch, and has the same effect:

```
int j = 2;

int A()
{
    j = 10;
    return 0;
}

j = j + A();
```

If you don't want to think in terms of local functions, you can also write this as a class:

```
class C
{
    private int j;

    public void Test()
    {
        j = 2;
        j = j + A();
    }

    private int A()
    {
        j = 10;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The compiler will:

1. Start by evaluating `j + A()`:

   1. Push the current value of `j`, which is `2`, onto the stack
   2. Call `A()`, which sets `j` to `10` and returns `0`
   3. Push the return value of `A()`, which is `0`, onto the stack
   4. Add together the two values on the stack: `2 + 0`
2. Assign this value to `j`

If you write the assignment the other way around, as `j = A() + j`, then its final value is `10`. If you follow the same sequence of steps as above, you'll see why.

---

This general approach -- changing a variable as a side-effect of an expression which also changes that variable -- is a bad idea. It leads to very hard-to-understand code.

Comment: Awesome, very clear explanation, thank you so much. It makes sense if you think about it in that way, cheers :)

Comment: Also, I am looking for the c# spec, so I can look at the article you mentioned but I can't find it, do you have a link?

Comment: @subalary They're linked from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions). E.g. [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029).